# Need to insert with smaller batches to Teradata table with pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am attempting to insert data from pandas dataframe into Teradata table via pyodbc in small batches.

I am able to insert a small sample set of data successfully, however when I attempt to insert the entire dataframe (about 125k rows), I receive this error message: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] SQL request exceeds maximum allowed length of 1 MB.

After doing some research, it appears that my insert statement is simply too large, so I would like to break this up into smaller batch sizes. I've researched cursor.executemany and it's requisite parameters, but I'm able to find anywhere to define a batch size.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

# Delete All Records pertaining to Max Report Month
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql_del = "DELETE FROM database.table WHERE RPT_MTH = '" + max_mth + "';"
cursor.execute(sql_del)
connection.commit()

# Insert All Predictions
data = df_prod.values.tolist()
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO database.table VALUES (?,?,?,?)', data)
connection.commit()

# Close Connections
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried `df_prod.to_sql('table', engine, schema='database', if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=1000)` ...?

Comment: @GordThompson I see, I did not try this one yet. How would I derive engine? My connection is derived this way:

`user = 'user'  
pasw = 'pasw'  
host = 'host'  
connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=Teradata;DBCNAME=' + host + ';UID=' + user + ';PWD=' + pasw + ';QUIETMODE=YES'
                            ,autocommit = True
                            ,unicode_results = True)`

Comment: Teradata recommends using their own SQLAlchemy dialect. Details [here](https://downloads.teradata.com/tools/articles/teradata-sqlalchemy-introduction).

Comment: @GordThompson, thanks for the info. I followed the instructions and installed the necessary libraries. However, I keep getting an error:

NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:teradata

Have you ever encountered this before?

Comment: I don't use Teradata myself, but [this issue](https://github.com/Teradata/sqlalchemy-teradata/issues/37) looks similar.

Comment: @GordThompson thanks again, I already came across this post and attempted that solution as well. Still not working unfortunately :/

I'll see if I can find another solution.

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](https://pastebin.com/jj06A4GM) might suffice?

Comment: @GordThompson I was actually able to get it to work using your suggestion, however it does not matter how large my chunksize paremeter is, it still inserts each individual record as a single query. We have a policy to disable User IDs after 5,000 queries in one day. Still need to figure out another solution.

Seriously, thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

@Justin 
If you have limitations of inserts/day, you may try using teradata recommended utilities like TPT, MLOAD directly from File, instead of using Py.

Comment: Yes this is always an option, I was simply attempting to keep it all in the same system versus invoking an automation process outside of python.